# ASP.NET MVC 3 - enabled unobtrusive javascript, ajaxComplete fires once and never again

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript

Before unobtrusive javascript, I handled ajax complete events with the following register:

```
Sys.Net.WebRequestManager.add_completedRequest(myHandler);
```

This event handler will fire every time an ajax request is complete. I also have an **ajaxComplete** event bind in $(document).ready(), to handle ajax calls exclusively through jQuery:

```
$.ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {
    myHandler(xhr)
});
```

Which also works great. But I get a different behavior when I enabled unobstrusive javascript in ASP.NET MVC 3. It fires the first time when the first ajax call is complete, but on subsequent ajax requests, ajaxComplete event never fires again.

Now, I know about that you need to call **$.validate.unobtrusive.parse()** to rebuild the validation after the elements in the form updated via partial postback. Is there something similar that I need to do to make sure that ajaxComplete can fire again on subsequent requests? I cannot find the documentation on this.

---

> FYI: I have included all the jquery*.js libs to support unobtrusive javascript. I also have the MicrosoftMvc*.js libs included to support legacy code in the project. I was hoping to convert everything over until I ran into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually attach ajaxComplete to an element I thought?

```
$('.info').ajaxComplete(function() {
   var info = $(this);
   info.html('Success!');
});
```

You should only need to attach ajaxComplete to an element once in its lifetime.